# Regex: Finding a value for a "key" inside brackets over multiple lines

Tags: regex

I'm currently having some trouble wrapping my head around regular expressions, which is where I hope some of you regex guru's out there might be able to assist with.

I'll briefly explain my problem with an example of what I am trying to achieve.
I have an input string, with a key and value I am looking for, which look somewhat like this:

- G01::Notice ((The customer already exists))
- G01::MyNotice ((The customer already exists, nevermind...))
- G02::OrderConfirm ((The order has been comfirmed!
  Please inform the customer that his orders will arrive soon.))

In the above examples, I would like to get everything for G01:: which is enclosed within the parentheses. So my pattern is

Looking at the three input strings, I should add a few notices:

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if your question is complete ...

Is it this what you want?

```
G01::[^(]*\(\(([^)]*)
```

See it here on [Regexr](http://regexr.com?2ts24). The text within the brackets is in the capture group 1.

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex: `G01::\w+ \(\((.*?)\)\)`

Answer (score 0):

Not a complete question, but how about this one?

```
.*\((.*?)\)

Result 1
The customer already exists

Result 2
The customer already exists, nevermind...

Result 3
The order has been comfirmed! Please inform the customer that his orders will arrive soon.
```

On [rubular](http://www.rubular.com/r/MozWQWRCwd)

Answer (score 0):

`G01.*\(\((.*)\)\)` seems to work (unless I misunderstood your question).